# React: onClick on Mobile (iPhone) requires 2 taps?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, mobile

[Video demonstrating issue](https://i.imgur.com/OF0F6QC.mp4)

I have a bunch of clickable components that, when clicked, adds a "card" to a row. On desktop, it works fine, but on mobile (tested on iPhone, does not seem to be an issue for Android tablet), it requires 2 consecutive taps of the same button to fire the `onClick` function.

These components also have `onMouseEnter`/`onMouseLeave` effects on them, to control a global state, which in turn decides if several components should have additional CSS applied (so I can't make it a simple CSS hover effect).

I believe that the mouse effects are interfering with the click event, but I have no idea how I could fix that. Here is the relevant code for this component:

```
const CardSource = ({ addCard, note, setHoveredNote, hoveredNote }) => {
  return (
    <Source
      onClick={() => addCard(note)}
      onMouseEnter={() => setHoveredNote(note)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHoveredNote(null)}
      className={
        hoveredNote && hoveredNote.index === note.index ? "highlight" : null
      }
    >
      {note.letters[0]}
    </Source>
  );
};
```

**Furthermore**, once a button *has* been tapped twice, the hover effect CSS "sticks" to that button, and never moves to another button. This seems to happen on both iPhone and Android tablet. I would love to have this not happen anymore either.

I've created a working demonstration of this issue in a sandbox, which if viewed on mobile you should be able to recreate these issues: https://codesandbox.io/s/mobile-requires-2-taps-i9zri?file=/src/Components/CardSource/CardSource.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use css `hover` rather than adding a class via `onMouseEnter` event, It fixes the two taps issue.

[Link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mobile-requires-2-taps-pfwhx?file=/src/Components/CardSource/CardSource.js)

If you were to programatically use trigger for hover. You could solve the two clicks issue by using `onTouchEnd` event (commented in sandbox).

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is definitely on the right track, but there are a few issues: 1) I should have mentioned it in the post, but I can't use a simple css hover because the state it sets gets passed to multiple components in my real project, which need to update css based on that. 2) The `onTouchEnd` does indeed make it work on 1 tap for iPhone, but `onTouchEnd` on its own does not allow for clicking, so now it doesn't work on Desktop. 3) Having both `onTouchEnd` and `onClick` active makes it fire twice on my Android tablet (frustratingly, not in your sandbox, but on my real project...)

Comment: Also, is there any documentation for `onTouchEnd`? I had searched for touch events before, but the only mention was on this page: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html, which offers no information about it at all

Comment: @damon -  [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ontouchend). If android is the last piece of puzzle, you can detect the user agent and conditionally apply the touchEnd (Hacky, i know).

Comment: Having looked at all the answers, I think I'll have to do a combination of `touch` events and user agent detection. Thanks a ton for taking the time to provide a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the problem with your code is, the mouse events you're using are **non-bubbling**. [e.g. mouseenter event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event).

You might want to try with an event bubbling solution using `onMouseOver` instead of `onMouseEnter`, and `onMouseOut` instead of `onMouseLeave`.

```js
const CardSource = ({ addCard, note, setHoveredNote, hoveredNote }) => {
  return (
    <Source
      onClick={() => addCard(note)}
      onMouseOver={() => setHoveredNote(note)}
      onMouseOut={() => setHoveredNote(null)}
      className={
        hoveredNote && hoveredNote.index === note.index ? "highlight" : null
      }
    >
      {note.letters[0]}
    </Source>
  );
};
```

Should the above NOT work, you could debug this with event type and performing event handling based on it. e.g.

```
const CardSource = ({ addCard, note, setHoveredNote, hoveredNote }) => {
  const eventHandler = (event) => {
     const { type, bubbles } = event;
     switch(type) {
         case "mouseover":
         case "mouseenter":
              setHoveredNote(note);
              break;
         case "mouseout":
         case "mouseleave":
              setHoveredNote(null);
         case "click":
              addCard(note);
              if (bubbles) { // handle hover state
                 setHoveredNote(note);
              }
              break;
         default:
             break;
     }
  }

  const onClick = (event) => eventHandler(event);
  const onMouseOver = (event) => eventHandler(event);
  const onMouseOut = (event) => eventHandler(event);

  return (
    <Source
      onClick={onClick}
      onMouseOver={onMouseOver}
      onMouseOut={onMouseOut}
      className={
        hoveredNote && hoveredNote.index === note.index ? "highlight" : null
      }
    >
      {note.letters[0]}
    </Source>
  );
};
```

> Also note that, providing arrow functions as props creates new instance of the function on every render. So better use bind in that case or just function references that capture the arguments.

Comment: I hadn't considered bubbling, so thank you for bringing that up. Having tested `Over` & `Out` instead of `Enter` & `Leave`, unfortunately, there seems to be no difference (other than the functions firing again when enter/leaving the letter within the square). I also used your debug function, and interestingly, when I logged the `bubbles` property for each mouse case - `over`, `enter`, `out`, and `leave`, they all returned `true`, even though `enter` and `leave` should have been `false`? Maybe there is a hint there?

Comment: It could also be a case where you might consider handling touch based events, as the events we are trying to handle are mouse events. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: Yes, I think touch events might need to be the solution. My only issue being that they don't seem to be well supported, and can cause a few issues when used simultaneously with hover / click events. Thanks for your answer and for suggesting using the event handling debug function, which is very helpful

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found the problem when I use an `onClick` & `onMouseEnter` & `onMouseLeave` then test in the browser in mobile mode the `onMouseEnter` and `onClick` event fire with the first `onClick`, you can add a console log to all your events and see the same behavior. The CSS style is staying because the DOM thinks that your element still has the hover attribute. If you click off of the element in question, you will see your `onMouseLeave` event fire, your css will reset but the element will require two clicks again. I'm not sure what the solution is, or if its even a problem testing on an actual mobile device.

EDIT: A solution I found, is only using the `onMouseEnter` & `onMouseLeave` event, since this event fires onClick for mobile and I only want the hover effect on desktop the outcome is what I was after.

EDIT EDIT: To maintain accessibility with the keyboard I added an `onKeyDown` event to open/close the dropdown button (which is what I was working on)

```js
onKeyDown={(event) => {
          if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            setShowChildren(showChildren === "hide" ? "show" : "hide");
          }
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar problem. The issue was for me that the [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html) of component does not change immediately, but only upon execution of the `render()` method. I believe you might have the same issue with asynchronicity for both effects you are describing.

The only `render()` call I see found in your code is in [`App.test.js`](https://codesandbox.io/s/mobile-requires-2-taps-i9zri?file=/src/App.test.js), I usually place that in the respective `component.tsx`.

#### References

- [Submit button takes 2 clicks to call function in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53399658/submit-button-takes-2-clicks-to-call-function-in-react)
- [React.js events need 2 clicks to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668062/react-js-events-need-2-clicks-to-execute)

Comment: @damon Let me know what you think. I will anyhow have a deeper look into your code if I have time today.

Comment: Sorry for the delay: On the note about the `render()` call, I believe the primary `render` function in my code example is in `index.js`. I don't think the `test.js` files are involved here. On the note about the state not updating immediately, I am not sure this is the same issue as your two references. I have had that same issue before, but in this instance, the state is updated successfully on the first tap, but there are technically 2 that should update: 1 for hover, and 1 for click. The fact that it works on desktop, but not mobile, make me think this is an interference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Use events `onTouchStart`, `onTouchMove`, `onTouchEnd` for calculate touch.